# Executing a program using fork and exec

Tags: c

I am new to C programming. I am trying to run a program given by the path specified by the user using the `fork()`, `exec()`, and `waitpid()` commands. I have been trying to get this to run correctly for hours now and I keep getting errors I am not sure how to troubleshoot, as soon as I solve one error, new ones arise. I was wondering if someone can help me understand why my implementation does not work smoothly?

Many thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void)  {
    char command1[256], command2[256], path[556];
    printf("# ");
    scanf("%s", command1);
    scanf("%s", command2);
    scanf("%s", path);
    if(strcmp(command1,"quit")==0)
        exit(0);
    else if(strcmp(command1, "run")==0 && strcmp(command2, "command")==0){

            printf("%s", path);

            pid_t process;

            process = fork();

            //fork error
            if (process < 0){
               perror("fork");
               exit(0);
            }
            else if (process > 0){  //this is the parent process
               execl(path, "sh" , "-c", ":ls -l *.c", 0);
            }
            else {//this is the child process
               waitpid(process); //waits until the program terminates 
            }

    }




return 0;

}
```

Comment: And what are the error messages?

Comment: 1. `#include <unistd.h>`, `#include <sys/wait.h>` and `#include <sys/types.h>`, then `pid_t waitpid(pid_t pid, int *status, int options);`. 2. `waitpid` waits for children to terminate, so you should `exec` in the child and wait in the parent.

Comment: @DanielFischer, when I follow step 1, I get an error saying that there is no such file or directory.

Comment: Looks like you got the terms "parent" and "child" reversed.

Comment: @MHZ What's your OS? Unless Windows, check the man pages for `fork` and `waitpid`. If Windows, iirc, there is no `fork`.

Comment: thanks for the catch, please see edited, now the parent and child are not labeled correctly?

Comment: Yes I am using Windows.

Comment: so my initial comments were corrct in that case

Comment: Daniel Fischer is correct: There is no fork() function on Windows. There is only CreateProcess(), but that creates a *new process*, not a copy of the calling process.

Comment: Yup, Daniel Fischer is right. fork/exec is only useful on Linux/Unix/Mac OS X; it won't work on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you have things swapped. With fork/exec, you generally do the exec in the child process, and the waitpid in the parent process.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After swapping, I am still getting an 'Linker Error' error that says that I have an `undefined reference to _fork`.

Comment: @MHZ: Windows does not have a fork() function, see my comment above.